# How to get value from JavaScript to homecontroller?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a timer in my project and when I stop it the timer value should be saved to the database, but I cannot get the value of the timer from JavaScript to the homecontroller.

**My JavaScript is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("starttime").innerHTML = ((hour<=9) ? "0"+hour : hour) + " : " + ((min<=9) ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec;
.
.
.
.
.
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#End").click(function () {
                 $.ajax({ url: '/Home/SaveAnsDetails?classs=' + ($("#txtClass").val())
                  + '&ExamDate=' + ($("#ExamDate").val())
                    + '&ddd=' + ($("#starttime").val()),<!--timer value starttime is passed to ddd-->
                     type: "Post",
                     dataType: "json",

                     success: function (message) {
                         alert(message);
                     }
                 });
             });
         });

</script>

<div id="starttime" style="font-size:large; "></div>
```

**Homecontroller coding is**

```
    [ActionName("SaveAnsDetails")]
    public ContentResult SaveAnsDetails(ModelGridAllFeatures model, IList<VW_Grid_Answer1> ds, string ExamDate, string ddd)
    {

    }
```

ddd get from starttime(timer value). when I get the ddd value in homecontroller it contains an empty value.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure on this parameter "ModelGridAllFeatures model" , but are you getting value for Examdate correspondingly?

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is wrong. Check out the documentation at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), especially look for the section **Sending Data to the Server**.

```
$.ajax({
    url:
        '/Home/SaveAnsDetails?classs=' + ($("#txtClass").val())
        + '&ExamDate=' + ($("#ExamDate").val())
        + '&ddd=' + ($("#starttime").val()),<!--timer value starttime is passed to ddd-->
    type: "Post",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (message) {
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

You have specified to make a post request, but you try to pass data along with the url, omitting the `data` setting. This is wrong. you need to specify the `data` setting if you use a post request like this. Use the following code in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:
        '/Home/SaveAnsDetails',
    data:
        'classs=' + ($("#txtClass").val())
        + '&ExamDate=' + ($("#ExamDate").val())
        + '&ddd=' + ($("#starttime").val()),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (message) {
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

In your Controller you need to specify the `[HttpPost]` attribute, to be able to distinguish the `POST` request from a `GET` request.

You don't pass a model to your controller. Instead you use the data passed into it to instantiate an object of your model class within the controller. With a `POST` request you have access to a `FormCollection` which holds the data. Use the [Model.TryUpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method in conjunction with the [Collection.ToValueProvider()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.tovalueprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method to write your values to the model. Your controller would look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAnsDetails(FormCollection collection)
{
    var model = new ModelGridAllFeatures();
    TryUpdateModel(model, new string[]
    {
        "classs",
        "ExamDate",
        "ddd"
    }, collection.ToValueProvider());
}
```

You can also combine `POST` requests with `GET` requests. You would pass in another parameter to your controller and edit your ajax request to use that parameter in the request url accordingly.

Comment: still i not able to get the value of timer(ddd)...i think some problem in <div id="starttime" style="font-size:large; "></div> where i display the timer value.. + '&ddd=' + ($("#starttime").val()) not getting value..any idea for it...

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#End").click(function () {
             $.ajax({ url: '/Home/SaveAnsDetails',
              data: {'classs': $("#txtClass").val(),
                     'ExamDate': $("#ExamDate").val(),
                     'ddd':$("#starttime").text()
                    },
              type: "Post",
              dataType: "json",
              contentType:'application/json',
              success: function (message) {
                     alert(message);
                 }
             });
         });
     });
```

Changes:

1. If its post request that you require then why send data over URL parameter, instead send it in body.
2. If you need 'Json' then you need to also specify the 'contentType' accordingly.
3. 'starttime' is div element and to get it's value the correct way is using text() jquery method.